# Measurability of a group action on a probability measure.

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory

Consider a measure space $(X,\mathcal{B})$ where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of some topology on $X$. Suppose that the topological group $G$ acts continuously on $X$ and $G$ is given its Borel $\sigma$-algebra, $\mathcal{A}$. Lastly suppose that we have some measure on $X$, $Q$.

My question is, under what conditions is the map $f:G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(g) = Q(g^{-1}B)$ measurable for all (fixed) $B \in \mathcal{B}$? I've tried to see if I could show this for open $B$ and then extend this to all sets in $\mathcal{B}$ but I haven't been able to show it for the open case.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: by act continuously you mean that the left multiplication $L_g : X \to X$ such that $L_g(x) = g \cdot x$ is continuous? Also, is G a topological group? (if so maybe you might want to assume that the action $\cdot : G \times X \to X$ is continuous)

Comment: Yes, I am assuming that $G$ is a topological group. By act continuously I mean that the action defined by $\cdot: G \times X \rightarrow X$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is easier than I am making it out to be. We have that

$Q(g^{-1}B) = \int I_B(gx)Q(dx)$.

By the continuity of the action, $I_B(gx)$ is measurable $\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B}$. Via results related to Fubini's theorem $I_B(gx)$ being measurable implies $f(g) =  \int I_B(gx)Q(dx)$ is measurable as desired.